# How to create dynamic textbox using asp.net and C#

Tags: asp.net

How to create dynamic textbox using asp.net and C# .how to store in database .please any one help me i am new to this .Thanks in advance

Comment: Both your requirements are a little vague, and probably separate issues. Could you show us what you *have* tried to do?

Comment: It's usually better if you post some code so we can see where you are.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you:
For Data access you can take a look here:
 1. http://www.asp.net/web-forms
 2. Download "Professional Asp.Net 4 (wrox)" or "Microsoft ASP.NET 4 Step by Step"

And the code for add textbox(in this case)dinamically in a gridview is like this

```
void addTextBoxInGridView()
        {
            int nr = 0, nc = 0;
            nr = this.GridView1.Rows.Count;
            if (nr > 0)
            {
                nc = this.GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells.Count;

                int r = 0, c = 0;
                for (r = 0; r < nr; r++)
                {
                    for (c = 0; c < nc; c++)
                    {
                        string v1 = "";
                        v1 =    HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(this.GridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Text.ToString());

                        TextBox textbox = new TextBox();
                        textbox.Text = v1;
                        textbox.EnableViewState = true;
                        textbox.Style["text-align"] = "center";
                        textbox.Width = 40;
                        textbox.ID = "txt" + Convert.ToString(r) + Convert.ToString(c);
                        this.GridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Controls.Add(textbox);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**Happy code!!**

Answer (score 0):

Here is some research for you that should get you headed in the right direction.

[Adding Controls to page dynamically](http://makhaai.blogspot.com/2010/07/server-side-code-code-snippet-for.html)

[Data Access in ASP.Net](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials)